# Why there is internet access issue in some devices of Samsung for flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-permissions

I am developing a flutter application where I need to check internet connection. But it is working fine for rest of the device except Samsung s23, Galaxy Z Fold5. I am checking the release apk, and do not have any real device access for this I could get any debug result.

In AndroidManifest, I have taken this permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here is the code, for checking for an internet connection:

```dart
final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');

try {
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        Get.snackbar('Internet', 'Navigate to Internet');
    } else {
        Get.snackbar('No Internet', 'Navigate to No Internet');
    }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
    Get.snackbar('No Internet', 'SocketException');
}
```

In release mode, it always shows the snackbar from the exception. I need to show the 'Navigate to Internet' snackbar.

Can I get any solution?

Comment: Did you see what the exception actually says?

Comment: Yes, I have seen the exception. `failed host lookup: example.com` this is what I am getting. Though I have solved issue using [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52156) in the Dart SDK for it. It was closed without a fix.

One suggestion there is to use the [internet_connection_checker_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker_plus) package, which seems to do exactly what you're trying to achieve.

To use it, add the following to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  internet_connection_checker_plus: ^2.1.0
```

And change your code to use it:

```dart
final hasInternet = await InternetConnection().hasInternetAccess;

if (hasInternet) {
    Get.snackbar('Internet', 'Navigate to Internet');
} else {
    Get.snackbar('No Internet', 'Navigate to No Internet');
}
```